# Event for clicking on row headers in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

What is the event that exclusively handles mouse clicks made only on Row Headers of DataGridView?

If there are none, what would be an alternative of handling this type of event?

Comment: Read here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheadermouseclick.aspx

Comment: What you want to achieve by clicking on headers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a new Winforms Project and copy-paste the code below :-

[image]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        var list = new List<Books>
                       {
                           new Books() {Title = "Harry Potter", TotalRating = 5},
                           new Books() {Title = "C#", TotalRating = 5}
                       };
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
        dataGridView1.RowHeaderMouseClick += new DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(OnRowHeaderMouseClick);
    }

    void OnRowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Clicked RowHeader!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get the row header by following code:

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick( _
    ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) _
    Handles dataGridView1.RowHeaderMouseClick

    Me.dataGridView1.SelectionMode = _
        DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect
    Me.dataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Selected = True

End Sub
```

or

```
void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //
        // Do something on double click, except when on the header.
        //
        if (e.RowIndex == -1)
        {
        //this is row header...
            some code here.
        }
       Code...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two events related to clicking on Row Headers.

1. [`RowHeaderMouseClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheadermouseclick.aspx)
2. [`RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheadermousedoubleclick.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

```
private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DataGridViewRow dr = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
                this.Hide();
                frmStock frm2 = new frmStock();
                frm2.Show();
                frm2.txtStockID.Text = dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                frm2.txtConfigID.Text = dr.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                frm2.txtProductname.Text = dr.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                frm2.txtFeatures.Text = dr.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                frm2.txtPrice.Text = dr.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                frm2.txtQty.Text = dr.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                frm2.txtTotalPrice.Text = dr.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
                frm2.dtpStockDate.Text = dr.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
                frm2.btnUpdate.Enabled = true;
                frm2.btnDelete.Enabled = true;
                frm2.btnSave.Enabled = false;
                frm2.label8.Text = label1.Text;
           }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```