# C#: Create click event for DataGridView column heading

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, mouseevent, datagridviewcolumn

I am trying to create a click event for a DataGridView column headers so that when the user clicks to reorder the data I can run code to draw the gantt chart in the new order (see screen shot below).

As you can see I want the user to be able to sort the datagridview and the gantt chart to respond to the re-ordering.

I have tried using the click event as per msdn, however this had no effect when i tested it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadermouseclick.aspx

```
private void dataCapPlan_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("OK");
    }
```

for DataGridView `dataCapPlan`

Any Ideas?

Much Appreciated!

[image: Form]

Comment: any way you could post the markup code for the datagridview and the event handling wire up code, if it's done in code?

Comment: Hi Roman, should now be included in Q. Thanks. Let me know if you need any more.

(PS the message box is just to test the click event is working)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Needed to add code:

```
dataCapPlan.ColumnHeaderMouseClick +=new DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(dataCapPlan_ColumnHeaderMouseClick);
```

see post:
[Event for clicking on row headers in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116290/event-for-clicking-on-row-headers-in-datagridview)

Comment: Perfect.  That's what i wanted to see where event handlers are wired up.  I am glad you found it.  I'd mark the answer complete.

Comment: Cheers Roman, thanks for your help mate. Yes I will do but have to wait 2 days until I can mark correct unfortunately. Maybe because of my low rep.