# CurrentRow.Headercell.Selected of DataGridView always be false in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In Visual Studio 2010.

1. Create a Visual C# "Window Form Application" project
2. Put a DataGridView component on the form and add some columns.
3. Create Mouse click event:

   ```
   private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
   {
       if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.HeaderCell.Selected)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Header Selected");
       }

       if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.HeaderCell.State != DataGridViewElementStates.None)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Not None");   
       }                
   }
   ```
4. Select a row by clicking a row header in run time, but never show any MessageBox.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if you clicked on a row header cell, either of these options will work fine:

- Handling [`CellClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick(v=vs.110).aspx) event of `DataGridView` and check if `e.ColumnIndex=1`
- Handling [`CellMouseClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellmouseclick(v=vs.110).aspx) event of `DataGridView` and check if `e.ColumnIndex=1`
- Handling [`RowHeaderMouseClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheadermouseclick(v=vs.110).aspx) event of `DataGridView`

**Code**

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == -1)
        MessageBox.Show(e.RowIndex.ToString());
}

private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == -1)
        MessageBox.Show(e.RowIndex.ToString());
}

private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == -1)
        MessageBox.Show(e.RowIndex.ToString());
}
```

**Why Selected Property of row header cell is False?**

This is designed this way and is documented in Remarks section of related msdn  document:

> [DataGridViewHeaderCell.Selected Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewheadercell.selected(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> This property is not meaningful for header cells.

Here is the source code of Selected property of [DataGridViewHeaderCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewheadercell(v=vs.110).aspx) that is the base calss for [DataGridViewRowHeaderCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowheadercell(v=vs.110).aspx), as you see it always returns false.

```
[Browsable(false), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public override bool Selected
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
    set
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString("DataGridView_HeaderCellReadOnlyProperty", new object[] { "Selected" }));
    }
}
```

**How can I check other properties of row header cell?**

Using [HeaderCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.headercell(v=vs.110).aspx) property if each row you can get or set properties of row header cell. For example in any of events that mentioned above, you can put these codes:

```
//Set Value property, to see the value you should increase RowHeaderWidths property of DataGridView 
this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].HeaderCell.Value = "Hi";

//Get Selected property that returns false always
MessageBox.Show(this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].HeaderCell.Selected.ToString());
```

Comment: Yes. I tried this. All of them worked fine. They can show the correct 'RowIndex' value.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, use `ColumnIndex==-1` works fine. However, I still want to know why `CurrentRow.HeaderCell.Selected` did't work fine, it's always `false`.

Comment: It's helpful !!  Thank you very much!!

Comment: @MysticLin It would be great if you consider also an upvote for accepted answer, it's not compulsory at all, but it's reasonable and recommended :)

Answer (score 0):

" := " is not an assignment operator = is.

and your code should be

```
DataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect;
```

[if you want to get rowheader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116290/event-for-clicking-on-row-headers-in-datagridview) this post will be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I did't describe well.  

I set DataGridView.SelectionMode := RowHeaderSelect in design time, set it from Property window of DataGridView component.